# Setting up Windows Server Failover Clustering in SoftLayer

Tags: windows-server-2012, cluster, failovercluster

I'm trying to create a Windows Server Failover Cluster. I've already create Active Directory successfully. I'm currently at this stage:

[image]

On the screenshot, the blurred place has subnet/network id, something like xxx.xx.xx.xxx/xx.

Next to it, it says "Click here to type an address". As long as I understand, I have to provide an address from the particular subnet.

Here is the issue.

I'm trying to set up the Failover Cluster in production environment, in SoftLayer. When I've tried the clustering in lab environment with Oracle's VirtualBox, I had no issues because the network was fully under my control on my local machine. However, in Softlayer, they do not provide a free/available IP addresses from subnets. So I have no public IP to put to that location.

What can I do in this case?

Comment: Get an IP address for your Failover Cluster. Besides the node IP addresses you need an extra one for the cluster itself.

Comment: Yes, but the hosting provider is not giving me any extra IP address from the particular subnet, but offering me IP address from other subnets. How can I use that IP addresses from other subnets? For example, if the current subnet/network is xxx.xx.xx.xxx/xx, the extra IP is yyy.yy.yy.yyy/yy. How can I handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried nor seen a cluster spun across 2 (or more) subnets, so I don't know exactly how that would be set up.

Since MS Failover Clustering supports having nodes reside in different IP subnets, I would place one of the nodes on the additional subnet using the extra IP address and the remaining IP from the main subnet I would use for the actual cluster itself.
I'd like to find out how that works out.

Here's some additional reading:
[Configuring Windows Failover Cluster Networks](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2014/02/20/configuring-windows-failover-cluster-networks.aspx)
[Network infrastructure and domain account requirements for a failover cluster](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771404.aspx#BKMK_Account_Infrastructure)